# Transition destroys SVG rotation

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation, transition

I am working on a JavaScript project, and as part of it, trying to rotate an svg path element around a given point.
Here is a simplified example of the js file:

```
var angle=0;
d3.select("#canvas")
  .append("path")
  .attr("id", "sector")
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("d", "M150,150 L150,50 A100,100 0 0,1 236.6,200 Z")
  .on("click", function(){
    console.log("click");
    angle=(angle+120)%360;
    d3.select("#sector")
      .transition().duration(2500) //removing this line leads to a nice transform attribute in the resulting html
      .attr("transform","rotate("+angle+",150,150)");
  })
```

And the html is just:

```
<svg id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vva7qvur/) you can find it on JSfiddle.

As the comment in the above excerpt suggests, it all works fine with the 3-argument version of the rotate function, where I can specify the x and y coordinates of the point which I want to use as the center of rotation. The resulting path element gets a transform attribute with the value of

```
"rotate(120,150,150)"
```

Unless I want to use a transition.

When I insert the line about the transition, the transformation gets some weird extra things added, it looks like

```
"translate(354.9038105676658, 95.09618943233417) rotate(119.99999999999999) skewX(-3.1805546814635176e-15) scale(0.9999999999999999,0.9999999999999999)"
```

I guess in the background the non-(0,0)-centered rotation gets replaced with some translations and a (0,0)-centered rotation, just as you can do it in geometry. The position and orientation after the transition is fine indeed. However, during the transformation the element is moving on a funny path, in the example the sector leaves the circle.

Is there a way I can suppress the transition doing all these transformations and just apply a single non-(0,0)-based rotation?
Are there any other workarounds?
Changing the transform-origin for the path element attribute did not seem to work, but maybe I was doing it wrong.
I am looking for a CSS-free solution. It is an architectural decision which I cannot overrule in the project.
As you see, D3 is already involved in the project, but I would like to use as few additional external libraries as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your arc with its center at (0,0). Then translate it to the center of the circle.
Then the d3 transition will work nicely as follows:

```
 d3.select("#sector")
  .transition().duration(2500)
  .attr("transform","translate(150,150)rotate("+angle+")");
```

Comment: Thanks, works really smooth! Just for reference, I made the corrected code available  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zymvac54/).